# Why checkbox value is on when it's unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

The problem is that I get **on** value from check box when it's checked and when it's unchecked... what do I miss?

HTML checkbox code :

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="noextracharge" name="noextracharge"  >
                <label for="noextracharge">no extra charge</label><br>
```

to get the values from page's inputs I use :

```
 function getInputValues() {  //var enabledInputs array of inputs ids
      
        var inputValues = {};
        $.each(enabledInputs, function (index, inputId) {
            var input = $(inputId);
            inputValues[input.attr("name")] = input.val();
        });
        return inputValues;
    };
```

Comment: What is `enabledInputs`  Please click `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with relevant HTML and script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always return the same.
To get if the checkbox is checked or not use `.is(":checked")`

if you need to check the type before use `prop("type") === "checkbox"`

Comment: ok is in this case I need to add a check if the input is checkbox and then use .is(":checked") ?

Comment: yes, please see my updated answer for the complete solution.